# Htaccess - 403 status code when executing PHP file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have created a directory named synchro under `C:/xampp/htdocs/`
and I have added a PHP script `test.php` that contains a webservice and I have generated a passwords file.

And to secure the folder I have added `.htaccess` file that contains:

```
Options +Indexes
AuthUserFile "C:/xampp/htdocs/synchro/passwords"
AuthName "Authentication required"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

But when I try to execute the PHP file

```
localhost/synchro/test.php
```

After entring login and password I got `Error 403`
How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you have a `.htpasswd` file?

Comment: No i just have .htaccess and passwords file

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the speech marks from around `AuthUserFile`. It should look like this:

```
AuthUserFile /xampp/htdocs/synchro/passwords
```

You then need a file called `.htpasswd`. This will be where you create your login and password.

For example:

```
Admin:gl0IiOirI2n6M
```

So your `AuthUserFile` will look like this:

`AuthUserFile /xampp/htdocs/synchro/.htpasswd`

Comment: i dont have problem with passwords it a 403 error and not 401. it means that the server recognized me but i just don’t have permission to access this resource.

Comment: Well, your `AuthUserFile` is incorrect. You also require `.htpasswd`. In regards to your 403, have you got directory browsing forbidden? Because that will explain your 403 error. Allow directory browsing and it should fix the error.